# fromHtml dont show images in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

i used retrofit 2 and get json content from my site.
json like this :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test title!",
    "content": " hello word! <img src="test.jpg"> , please click <a href="http://test.com/">here</a>",
    "avatar": "https://test.com/p152.png"
}
```

i get json with recyclerview adapter :

```
holder.title.setText(posts.get(position).getTitle());    

holder.content.setText(fromHtml(posts.get(position).getContent()));

Picasso.with(context).load(posts.get(position).getAvatar()).into(holder.avatar);           
holder.avatar.setTag(posts.get(position).getAvatar());
```

title and avatar are shown without problem.
but in content img not shown as image,
and href not shown as link.

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html?hl=de#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)), to process img tag you need to implement your own Html.ImageGetter.

Comment: thanks, but how can i  implement Html.ImageGetter for my recyclerview adapter?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Borales/7531445) is an example, but also you can find many examples when google it

Comment: i see all of them but everyone had a problem.i want the exactly code please.

Comment: I added it in the previous comment click on "Here"